# DB::table() method not found, laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I researched the net, but couldnt find a solution to my problem.

I cant get an element from my database.

```
   <?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Wishlist extends Model
{
    public $table = 'wishlist';
    public $fillable = ['book_id','user_id',];

    public function books() //one-to-many
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public static function myWishlist()   
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $wishlist = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->pluck('wishlist_id');
        $wishlist_id = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('wishlist_id'); 
        return Book::where('wishlist_id', $wishlist_id);
    }
}
```

If I fill in hard: 'return Book::where('whishlist_id', 1);' it shows it correctly. But neither 'wishlist' nor 'wishlist_id' shows it.

I would be so happy to get help!

Comment: Try `var_dump`'ing `$wishlist_id`, is it what you expect it to be? Note that the variable `$wishlist` is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation of the pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) states.

> The pluck method retrieves ***all of the values*** for a given key

the `pluck` method will return an `array` of all values 'plucked'.

This means

```
User::where('id', $id)->pluck('wishlist_id');
```

Will return an array containing 1 element that is the desired `wishlist_id`

The correct syntax would be something like:

```
User::where('id', $id)->pluck('wishlist_id')[0];
```

Assuming a user always has a  `wishlist_id`.

Comment: @L.Lehmann Glad to help! Don't forget you can always test queries like this using the `php artisan tinker` command to see what your code would return. You can read more about it here: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tinker